# Mongodb how to do $lookup to find matching documents with a field in an array list

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of portfolios like:

```
{"title":String,"isinList":[{"isinNo":String,"weight":Number}], ...}
```

For the isinNo, I have another collection as product_master. Now I want to do a lookup on product_master to fetch all information for the ISIN like:

```
[
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'let': {
                'isins': '$isinList.isinNo'
            }, 
            'from': 'product_master', 
            'as': 'instruments', 
            'pipeline': [
                {
                    '$match': {
                        'body.ISIN': {
                            '$in': '$$isins'
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

However here, I am getting an error '$in needs an array'. If I do $addField as '$isinList.isinNo', it adds up an array of ISINs.
I am not getting it clear as to where is it going wrong. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: 1. Would be great if you can share the sample document. 2. In `$lookup` pipeline, you need work with `$expr`: `{ $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$body.ISIN", "$$isins" ] } }`

Comment: You should use the syntax of [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) in aggregation pipeline instead of the [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) in query operator.

Comment: Have you tried a simple lookup like `{'$lookup': { 'localField':isinList.isinNo', 'foreignField':'body.ISIN', 'from': 'product_master', 'as': 'instruments' }}`?  Like this: [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XgD7XpuhI0R)